# What are the rest of seven underwater kingdoms?

Tags: analysis, dc-extended-universe, aquaman

In *Aquaman*, it was said multiple times that there are seven underwater kingdoms  in need to be united, and that was even used in early *Aquaman* posters:

[image: Aquaman poster reading "Unite the Seven"]

But in film I can only see Atlantis, Kingdom of the Brine, tribe of Xebel and The Trench but what about the rest? Do we get to know what are the remaining three?

Comment: Out-of-universe it's most likely a nod to [the seven seas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_Seas).

Answer (score 9):

Copy-pasting my answer to [What are the Seven Kingdoms in Aquaman?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/202005/98028) on SFF:

1. Atlantis. No need to explain that one, I think.
2. Xebel, ruled by King Nereus. IIRC Xebel isn't shown in the movie.
3. The Trench, inhabited by monsters.
4. The Fishermen Kingdom, <s>land</s> waters of the mermaid-looking people.
5. The Brine, with its crab-like people, and where the final battle begins.
6. The Deserters Kingdom, now buried in the Sahara after it was draught.
7. > The Hidden Sea (in Earth's Core, no less), where Atlan's trident was hidden, and which can be accessed from the portal thingy beyond the Trench.

Comment: Are you sure you #7 is actually a Kingdom and not just the place of King Atlan's exile? - When Orm and Nereus first meet at the Council of Kings (right before the false flag submarine attack) they call the 7th Kingdom __The Lost Nation__.

Comment: @Oliver_C I got the feeling that it was the 7th kingdom as it seemed to have manmade constructions (throne room of sorts) and was introduced similarly to the others. Plus, it fitted the "lost nation" part as it was not easy to find.

Comment: While that's possible, Vulko said that King Atlan went into self imposed exile and was never seen again. But if #7 was one of the Kingdoms he ruled over, then going there for exile wouldn't make sense (I'm guessing that back then all 7 Kingdoms still existed).

Comment: @Oliver_C From what I've been able to gather, the to-be Kingdoms actually existed before Atlantis sunk, in a way similar to provinces... what if... the 7th (Lost) Kingdom was almost completely obliterated during the Atlantis sinking (which is, AFAIK, the case in some Aquaman timelines) - wouldn't it be the best place for the King to retreat exactly there on his exile?

Comment: It's possible that the Lost Nation got lost during the sinking, but I don't remember Arthur, Mera or Atlanna ever calling #7 the Lost Kingdom or Lost Nation. - And judging by the animals that roam that place, it must have existed long before Atlantis. So maybe those ruins belong to a civilization older than Altantis (Poseidon?), or maybe it was actually the Trenchers who set up shop there (before they regressed). - Right now I feel like we don't have enough information to say for sure that #7 was the 7th Kingdom.

Answer (score 2):

While there is quite a bit we do not know about the fictional fantasy world of Atlantis, we have been told that Atlantis split into 7 kingdoms. Four specifically mentioned in the movie, three to remain largely a mystery, or at least a puzzle, but truly six kingdoms are represented in the movie.. Fandom's website has listed all seven, but their pages are little more than placeholders for future content.  It stands to reason:

1. [Atlantis, remains a
   kingdom](https://dccomicsextendeduniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Atlantis)

The seven kingdoms split from Atlantis, but did not destroy Atlantis. Atlantis, and three other kingdoms allegiance were necessary for *King Orm* to hold the title *Ocean Master*.

2. The [Fisherman
   Kingdom](https://dccomicsextendeduniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Fisherman_Kingdom)

...seem to go along, reluctantly. As *Arthur/Aquaman* and *Mera* head off to find *King Atlan and the Trident*, they fight off creatures from the

3. [Trench
   Kingdom](https://dccomicsextendeduniverse.fandom.com/wiki/The_Trench),

diving into the water to find the

4. [Missing
   Kingdom (aka the Lost Nation)](https://dccomicsextendeduniverse.fandom.com/wiki/The_Missing_Kingdom)

where *King Atlan* leaves cryptic clues to the location of his famed Trident.
Their journey continues when they,  quite unexpectedly, find  *Mom/Atlana* in the center of and at the bottom of the ocean in what appears to be a rather nice piece of real estate. Stuck for a couple of decades because she wasn't able to get the *Trident* herself (the key to leaving). This idyllic setting is likely the:

5. [Deserter
   Kingdom](http://dcextendeduniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Kingdom_of_the_Deserters).

Apparently, the only people able to speak to sea creatures  are *King Atlan* and *Arthur/Aquaman*. Once the gi-normous crustacean stops fighting *Arthur/Aquaman*, it breaks free from the lava laden depths to help *Aquaman* claim his title as *True King/Ocean Master*. The scene takes place in the

6. [Brine Kingdom](https://dccomicsextendeduniverse.fandom.com/wiki/The_Brine)

The only kingdom that I do not remember from the movie is

7. [Xebel](https://comicvine.gamespot.com/xebel/4020-57137/)

Once ruled by *Mera*  and originally an "other-demensional" kingdom, now a penal colony for Atlantean crimes. But don't confuse that with the name *Xebel*, there seems to be some confusion between film and comic references. In the comic, *King Nereus* is *Mera's* fiancee, not father.

> [Aquaman's Seven Kingdom of Atlantis,
>   Explained](https://www.cbr.com/aquaman-seven-kingdom-atlantis-explained/):
>   But it's possible -- maybe even likely -- that the Lost Kingdom is
>   actually where Arthur and Mera discover Atlan's tomb, the Hidden Sea
>   at the Earth's core.

Comment: The Deserter kingdom is the one in the Sahara. Mera mentions a tribe splitting up from the rest, establishing a colony there and dying when it was draught. And there was a "Deserter's kingdom" label as well when (spoilers!) Arthur and Mera fall under the sand dunes and find the mechanism to read the message capsule thingy.